# Ionic 5 + Angular 9 - NgModule Register Error

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutPage } from './about.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AboutPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AboutPageRoutingModule {}
```

this above is my routing module of page about in my project

i need know is correct like this way or missing something yet?

when i running IONIC SERVE and debug

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24128)
    at core.js:24139
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24139)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:24236)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:27779)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:28017)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (wp-posts.ts:16)
```

in browser show this error

in debug this is the code with error

```
function registerNgModuleType(ngModuleType) {
    if (ngModuleType.ɵmod.id !== null) {
        const id = ngModuleType.ɵmod.id;
        const existing = modules.get(id);
        assertSameOrNotExisting(id, existing, ngModuleType);
        modules.set(id, ngModuleType);
    }
    let imports = ngModuleType.ɵmod.imports;
    if (imports instanceof Function) {
        imports = imports();
    }
    if (imports) {
        imports.forEach(i => registerNgModuleType(i));
    }
}
```

return error below with error in class HttpClient

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
  at registerNgModuleType (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:65982:27)
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:65993:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:65993:17)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:66090:13)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:69633:27)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:69871:16)
    at Module../src/main.ts (http://localhost:8100/main.js:1369:100)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/runtime.js:85:30)
    at Object.0 (http://localhost:8100/main.js:4234:18)
```

my "app.module.ts" is below

```
import {NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, ErrorHandler, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouteReuseStrategy} from '@angular/router';
import {IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy} from '@ionic/angular';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {IonicStorageModule, Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

import {Globalization} from '@ionic-native/globalization/ngx';
import {GoogleAnalytics} from '@ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx';

import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { NativeGeocoder } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
import { GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';

import {EmailComposer} from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';
import {SocialSharing} from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
import {Toast} from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';

import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';


import {JwtClientProvider} from '../providers/jwt-client/jwt-client';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';
import { JwtHelperService, JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import {AuthProvider} from '../providers/auth/auth';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth/auth-guard.service';

import {DefaultXHRBackendProvider} from '../providers/default-xhr-backend/default-xhr-backend';
import {RedirectorProvider} from '../providers/redirector/redirector';

import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import {UserResourceProvider} from '../providers/user-resource/user-resource';

import {GooglePlus} from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
import {TwitterConnect} from '@ionic-native/twitter-connect/ngx';

import {PaymentResource} from '../providers/payment-resource/payment-resource';
import {AccountResource} from '../providers/account-resource/account-resource';
import {BankDraftResource} from '../providers/bank-draft-resource/bank-draft-resource';
import {DonationResource} from '../providers/donation-resource/donation-resource';
import {NumberFormatProvider} from '../providers/number-format/number-format';
import {WpPostsProvider} from '../providers/wp-posts/wp-posts';
import {AppConfigProvider} from '../providers/app-config/app-config';

import {Network} from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import {NetworkCheckProvider} from '../providers/network-check/network-check';
import {FileTransfer} from "@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx";
import {FileChooser} from "@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx";
import {TicketResourceProvider} from '../providers/ticket-resource/ticket-resource';
import {AccountPageModule} from "../pages/account/account.module";
import {LanguagePageModule} from "../pages/language/language.module";
import {ProductFilter, ProductResourceProvider} from '../providers/product-resource/product-resource';
import {CartProvider} from '../providers/cart/cart';
import {SaleResourceProvider} from '../providers/sale-resource/sale-resource';
import {ApiConfigurationProvider} from '../providers/api-configuration/api-configuration';
import {ProfileBankDraftResourceProvider} from '../providers/profile-bank-draft-resource/profile-bank-draft-resource';
import {ConfigurationResourceProvider} from '../providers/configuration-resource/configuration-resource';
import {BankDraftConfigResourceProvider} from '../providers/bank-draft-config-resource/bank-draft-config-resource';
import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
import {GeocodingApiProvider} from '../providers/geocoding-api/geocoding-api';
import {RefundResourceProvider} from '../providers/refund-resource/refund-resource';
import {MaskNumber} from "../models/mask-number";
import {ProductListFilterOptionsPageModule} from "../pages/product-list-filter-options/product-list-filter-options.module";
import { BanksResource } from '../providers/banks-resource/banks-resource';
import { InstitutesResourceProvider } from '../providers/institutes-resource/institutes-resource';
import { MaterialsResourceProvider } from '../providers/materials-resource/materials-resource';
import { StatesResourceProvider } from '../providers/states-resource/states-resource';
import { ProfileResourceProvider } from '../providers/profile-resource/profile-resource';

import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';

import { ItemsResourceProvider } from '../providers/items-resource/items-resource';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

export function appInitFactory(appConfig) {
    return () => appConfig.load();
}


export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ProductListFilterOptionsPageModule,
        AccountPageModule,
        LanguagePageModule,
        NgxMaskModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClient,
        HttpModule,
        HttpParams,
        HttpHeaders,
        HttpClientModule,
        JwtHelperService,
        // Jwt Token Injection
        JwtModule.forRoot({
          jwtOptionsProvider: {
              provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
              useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
              deps: [AuthService]
          }
        }),

        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
            driverOrder: ['localstorage']
        }),
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: environment.GOOGLE_API_KEY
        })
    ],
    exports: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            deps: [AppConfigProvider],
            useFactory: appInitFactory,
            multi: true
        },
        AuthService,
        AuthGuardService,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        Globalization,
        GoogleAnalytics,
        GooglePlus,
        TwitterConnect,
        SocialSharing,
        EmailComposer,
        Toast,
        Facebook,
        Geolocation,
        NativeGeocoder,
        GoogleMaps,
        Device,
        AuthProvider,
        RedirectorProvider,
        UserResourceProvider,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
        {provide: XHRBackend, useClass: DefaultXHRBackendProvider},
        RedirectorProvider,
        UserResourceProvider,
        PaymentResource,
        AccountResource,
        BankDraftResource,
        DonationResource,
        NumberFormatProvider,
        WpPostsProvider,
        AppConfigProvider,
        Network,
        NetworkCheckProvider,
        FileTransfer,
        FileChooser,
        TicketResourceProvider,
        ProductResourceProvider,
        ProductFilter,
        CartProvider,
        SaleResourceProvider,
        ApiConfigurationProvider,
        ProfileBankDraftResourceProvider,
        ConfigurationResourceProvider,
        BankDraftConfigResourceProvider,
        GeocodingApiProvider,
        RefundResourceProvider,
        MaskNumber,
        BanksResource,
        InstitutesResourceProvider,
        MaterialsResourceProvider,
        StatesResourceProvider,
        StatesResourceProvider,
        ProfileResourceProvider,
        MaterialsResourceProvider,
        ItemsResourceProvider
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}

export function jwtOptionsFactory(authService) {
  return {
      tokenGetter: () => {
          return authService.getToken();
      },
  }
}
```

please some one help me debug my code to find the error and continue development

remenber this code is from ionic 3

i think is better run a new project with last angular and put old code in some little parts
is me correct with this thinking?

if some find for me my mistake i thankful

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure what's the question, the code looks fine.

Comment: @sebaferreras take a look again

Comment: ng build --prod show me erros and i fixed to solved my problems

Comment: Glad to hear that! Curious to know what was the error at the end

Comment: some imports like:    ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule and forms not know elements, navParms, i mean all about migration from ionic 3 to 5